# How to import multiple text files into columns of single excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have been trying to figure out how to take several hundred tab-delimited text files and import the data into subsequent columns of a single excel worksheet. The text files contain I(V) data with two columns and a header. I have found code/manipulated it to be able to remove the header and import into individual worksheets within a workbook but would like to be able to get the two columns of data from each worksheet into a single worksheet (i.e. columns from first text file to columns A & B of one worksheet, columns from second text file to columns C & D, etc.).  Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
      Rows("1:20").Select
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
              Rows("1:20").Select
              Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Here is an example of one of my I(V) data files:

```
    Notes: 

Timestamp: 7/19/2018 8:36:11 AM

Channel: Channel A

NPLC: 1

Current Limit: 0.010000

Pulse Mode: 0

Bias Pulses: 1

Bias Level: 0.000000

Settling Time: 0.500000

Voltage (V) Current (A)

-1.00000E+0 -6.95885E-7
-9.50000E-1 -6.47828E-7
-9.00000E-1 -6.06955E-7
-8.50000E-1 -5.53913E-7
-8.00000E-1 -5.00038E-7
-7.50000E-1 -4.51646E-7
-7.00000E-1 -4.02903E-7
-6.50000E-1 -3.58851E-7
-6.00000E-1 -3.19926E-7
-5.50000E-1 -2.73332E-7
-5.00000E-1 -2.33349E-7
-4.50000E-1 -1.99018E-7
-4.00000E-1 -1.62825E-7
-3.50000E-1 -1.31703E-7
-3.00000E-1 -1.04510E-7
-2.50000E-1 -8.06238E-8
-2.00000E-1 -5.88286E-8
-1.50000E-1 -4.14340E-8
-1.00000E-1 -2.58151E-8
-5.00000E-2 -1.24138E-8
0.00000E+0  5.52116E-11
5.00000E-2  1.26769E-8
1.00000E-1  2.64685E-8
1.50000E-1  4.17401E-8
2.00000E-1  5.97095E-8
2.50000E-1  7.98343E-8
3.00000E-1  1.02119E-7
3.50000E-1  1.28176E-7
4.00000E-1  1.57270E-7
4.50000E-1  1.89915E-7
5.00000E-1  2.29916E-7
5.50000E-1  2.72104E-7
6.00000E-1  3.35173E-7
6.50000E-1  4.53464E-7
7.00000E-1  6.12379E-7
7.50000E-1  7.97423E-7
8.00000E-1  9.75624E-7
8.50000E-1  1.16841E-6
9.00000E-1  1.34435E-6
9.50000E-1  1.52710E-6
1.00000E+0  1.75166E-6
1.00000E+0  1.81262E-6
9.50000E-1  1.72918E-6
9.00000E-1  1.63206E-6
8.50000E-1  1.52714E-6
8.00000E-1  1.42523E-6
7.50000E-1  1.32162E-6
7.00000E-1  1.21624E-6
6.50000E-1  1.11347E-6
6.00000E-1  1.00770E-6
5.50000E-1  9.05824E-7
5.00000E-1  8.08058E-7
4.50000E-1  7.09499E-7
4.00000E-1  6.14927E-7
3.50000E-1  5.26256E-7
3.00000E-1  4.38557E-7
2.50000E-1  3.53943E-7
2.00000E-1  2.74731E-7
1.50000E-1  1.98096E-7
1.00000E-1  1.27457E-7
5.00000E-2  6.16247E-8
0.00000E+0  -8.63841E-11
-5.00000E-2 -5.78634E-8
-1.00000E-1 -1.15769E-7
-1.50000E-1 -1.73858E-7
-2.00000E-1 -2.33503E-7
-2.50000E-1 -2.94364E-7
-3.00000E-1 -3.59336E-7
-3.50000E-1 -4.24816E-7
-4.00000E-1 -4.92460E-7
-4.50000E-1 -5.61514E-7
-5.00000E-1 -6.32542E-7
-5.50000E-1 -7.06702E-7
-6.00000E-1 -7.83559E-7
-6.50000E-1 -8.63077E-7
-7.00000E-1 -9.49685E-7
-7.50000E-1 -1.03839E-6
-8.00000E-1 -1.12932E-6
-8.50000E-1 -1.22503E-6
-9.00000E-1 -1.31770E-6
-9.50000E-1 -1.42892E-6
-1.00000E+0 -1.53654E-6
```

None of the header information is needed, which is why I am currently just deleting the first 20 rows. I have basic programming experience but very little with VBA. Any help with this particular problem is greatly appreciated!

-Tory

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sDelimiter As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sDelimiter = "|"
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

iDestCol=1
For x = 0 to Ubound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
       Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
       ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
       Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
       Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
       Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    wbkTemp.Range("A:B").Copy Destination:=wkbAll.Cells(1, iDestCol)
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    iDestCol = iDestCol + 2
  Next

  Rows("1:20").Delete Shift:=xlUp

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: I couldn't get this code running correctly.  I got two errors, one subscript error and one for invalid object. I changed x=1 in the for loop to fix the first error but the second had to do with the lines:                                   
    wbkTemp.Range("A:B").Copy Destination:=wkbAll.Cells(1, iDestCol)
    wkbTemp.Close (False).  Thanks for the input.  I did manage to get code working that I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to get two macros coded to do what I need.  I have one for pulling the data in from selected text files into individual sheets and another to consolidate the sheets into columns of a single sheet.  The code for the first macro is here:

```
Sub TextToSheets()
 Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Name = Dir(FilesToOpen(x))
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
      Range("A19:B19").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Name
      Range("A20").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Voltage (V)"
      Range("B20").Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current (A)"
      Rows("1:18").Select
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Name = Dir(FilesToOpen(x))
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
              Range("A19:B19").Select
              ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Name
              Range("A20").Select
              ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Voltage (V)"
              Range("B20").Select
              ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Current (A)"
              Rows("1:18").Select
              Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

And for the second here:

```
Sub CombineSheetsToColumns()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Summary").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
n = Application.Worksheets.Count
Sheets.Add.Name = "Summary"
Sheets("Summary").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set MerPos = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 3))

Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sh.Name <> "Summary" And sh.Name <> Sheets(n + 1).Name Then
Set col = Columns(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    sh.Range("A:A,B:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range(col, col).Offset(0, 1)
    MerPos.Select
    Selection.Merge
    Set MerPos = Range(MerPos.Offset(0, 1), MerPos.Offset(0, 2))
End If
Next sh
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Sheets("Summary").Select
Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Columns.AutoFit = xlColumn
End Sub
```

I added a few lines for adding text and formatting but shouldn't be too hard to get it working for whatever you may need to use it for.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy/paste data across a sheet, run the code below.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\LinkedIn\Import All Text Files Into One Single Sheet with File Name in Column A\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
'Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    ActiveCell = file.Name

    ' open the file
    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file)

    col = 2
    Do While Not txtFile.AtEndOfStream
        dat = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Split(txtFile.ReadLine, ","), 1, 0))
        sh.Cells(LastRow, col).Resize(UBound(dat), 1) = dat
        col = col + 1
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    txtFile.Close
    'Range(cl.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you want to copy/paste data down a sheet, run the code below.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\LinkedIn\Import All Text Files Into One Single Sheet with File Name in Column A\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    cl.Value = file.Name

    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```